# Need a help with 3D Low Frequency Wakeup Receiver AS3933

Tags: transmitter, receiver

I am software developer and I am totally new to circuits field.

Can somebody help me to understand how the 125 kHz transmitter and AS3933 receiver works?

This is the link where it says how it function, but the steps they have given  is very generic for me to understand.

http://www.ams.com/eng/content/download/200176/865682 (link goes to a 4.3MB PDF)

The steps they gave in the document (p.4) are as follows:

> - Connect the +9V DC power supply F to the 125kHz Wake-up Transmitter Board.
> - Insert the +3V battery at H of the AS3933 Demoboard
> - Turn on the AS3933 Demoboard via the ON/OFF-Switch C. All LEDs flash up once.
> - Start transmitting wake-up patterns via AUTO E of PATTERN B.
> - As soon as the AS3933 Demoboard receives a wake-up pattern the RSSI LEDs flash up for
>     0.5s and show the momentary received signal strength. At the same time the X, Y, or Z LED flash up indicating which channel receives the
>     strongest signal

Basically what I am looking for from member of this forum , is to demonstrate what should I do in order to test this development kit. I mean 1st, 2nd , 3rd and...so on steps.

I also want to know in what specific distance this circuit will transmit and receive the signal?

Comment: Please don't write in all-capitals.  The "thank you in advance" cuteness doesn't fly here either.  Appreciation is expressed with carefully formulated questions and  up-votes.  I have edited yous post to show you what a well-formed post on EE.SE should look like.

Answer (score 1):

I have done many Design Verification Test (DVT) plans and executed them in my past life.

You start by scoping the project with goals, so this answer part 1 to your question part 1.

- objective or mission
- time frame
- budget
- Resource limitations
- deliverables or expected outcome or plan B

  - List of faults and limitations to work with in the present design or
  - Green light specs, Red Flag issues
  - Market benchmark comparison , cost/performance rating, target markets
  - range of Environmental specs; Climate, mechanical,  electrical, electromagnetic, interference, BER margins ( includes shake & bake , pack & drop )

  Basic plan

  - Order parts, coils etc
  - Decide which functions you don't need to test
  - verify users manual
  - choose different 3 axis coils to compare RF vs data rate vs sync type vs distance vs power levels, whch affects; range, cost, application.
  - create a spreadsheet for test plan, results and design of experiment DOE
    Then do prelim. Performance test and tune and once OK, working, start the DVT.

Plan on many plots of Bit Error Rate BER vs all the above variables
Decide which applications match each setting options

In layman's terms , this is Near Field Communication ( NFC ) radio that is going to change the world in the next 10 yrs. Mobile apps can communicate with any object , a box, a car, your home furnace, your diving buddies and their tank pressure, your SOC medical lab on a chip, etc etc

Why ?  because the BOM cost is <3$ in 10k volume